# Passing python variable in sql script in where clause

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

am facing issue. I have write sql script to insert data into genre table.

```
for genre in movie_a['genres']:
cursor.execute("""
        if not exists (
        select * from genres
        where genre_title = ?
        )
        begin
            insert into genres values(?)
        end      
""", genre, genre)
```

am getting following error.

```
ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'genres'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

Single movie instance have multiple genres, so I want to insert them in genre table and avoid duplicates. Am using sql-server and there is no option for **INSERT IGNORE**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that your table is actually called `genre` but you are referring to it as `genres` within your SQL?

Comment: Right, my table name was genre, you saved my day.

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as correct